# Error says that a type exists in two assemblies, but one assembly is not even installed?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have this error

```
Error   CS0433  The type 'ApiController' exists in both 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' Project.SubProject.TestProject  C:\Project.SubProject.TestProject\Utility.cs
```

I want to use System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.7.0.

When I edit the project file, the other assembly (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim) cannot be found anywhere.  So there is no second assembly to delete.

Even if I search my entire solution for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim, there are no results.  So I'm totally stuck because this makes no logical sense to me; why is the compiler complaining about an assembly that I don't have installed?

Comment: You can explicity declare which version to use replace `ApiController` with `System.Web.Http.ApiController`

Comment: This doesn't work.  The same error persists

Comment: Please, share an [mcve]

Comment: Here is a [similar issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5861#issuecomment-282796227) maybe you can refer to.